# Why do I get error "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" using netsh set route?

Tags: windows-7, networking

On a windows7 machine I was trying to set the standard gateway following [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/293064/change-gateway-on-windows-7-from-command-line) example:

```
netsh.exe interface ipv4 set route 0.0.0.0/32 "Internet" 172.16.5.1
```

which returned the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Why is that the case, and how can I fix set the standard gateway for my connections?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by `0.0.0.0/32`? This won’t ever match anything, except `0.0.0.0`. `0.0.0.0/8` is a reserved net.

Comment: @Daniel: So the example in the link given does not make any sense?

Comment: Exactly, it’s simply wrong. You can easily check this yourself: run `netsh interface ipv4 show route` and you’ll see the default gateway has `0.0.0.0/0` as its target network.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use your real interface's name instead of `"Internet"`. You can list them with `netsh interface show interface`.

Answer (score 3):

There's some kind of an "underlying name" to the interface, set up on its 1st creation, or when it's manually changed. You can get it using:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show config
```

It might be different from what you see in the GUI window or from running `netsh interface show interface`

Try using **that** interface name instead - this worked for me on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar same issue. The problem was the " character. I copied the netsh from a word document I got from our software vendor and pasted that directly into the CMD and changed the needed parts which failed with the error mentioned here. However when I copied the string at first to notepad and replaced one from the " I discovered that they are different, so I replaced both / re-typed both and the issue is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently on Windows 7, you need to use a different syntax to execute the command in the correct context. Preface the context specifiers **interface ipv4** with a **-c** parameter and quote the entire context specifier. For example, to set the adapter to DHCP:

```
netsh -c "interface ipv4" set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```